# Allow access to anonymous client for specific pages using index.html and web.config

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have a web application, where i want to load homepage and one more page to be able to access by anonymous without authentication, whereas for other pages it requires authentication. In the webconfig file i did the below changes. But still I could see that for homepage it asks for credentials.

```
 <location path="app/components/home/home.html">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="*"/> 
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
<system.web>
<authorization>
      <allow roles="BUILTIN\Administrators" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="app/components/home/home.html">
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
        <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
      </authentication>
 </security>
</system.webServer>
<location path="app/components/home/home.html">
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
 </security>
</system.webServer>
```

I have index.html in my project which looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="app/assets/img/favicon.ico">
    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link href="" rel="stylesheet" />


    <link href="app/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="app/components/home/home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href= "othersheets"/>
    <link href="othersheets"/>
    <link href="othersheets"/>

 <script src="app/assets/vendor/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/assets/vendor/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/assets/vendor/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/assets/vendor/scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<script src="app/components/home/home.js"></script>
<script src="otherjs files"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="dApp">
    <dcheader></dcheader>
    <div class="main-content">
        <side-nav></side-nav>
        <div class="right-pane">
            <main ui-view class="content"></main>
            <dcfooter></dcfooter>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I removed all the link href and script src path to all other pages where authentication is needed, and kept only home page where it doesnot require authentication. With this changes i am able to access homepage without authentication, but it doesnot show any other tabs as well.

My requirement is without removing other tabs, all the tabs should be visible. But the homepage access should be allowed for anyone without authentication, where when the user clicks on anyother tab it should ask for authentication. How do I acheive this?

Comment: You may also have to set the access in IIS Manager, [check this out](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/adminstudio115sp1/Content/ashelplibrary/AMSIISAuth.htm)

Comment: yes i did this as well. I just disabled anonymous authentication for pages which requires authentication, and allowed for others. With all these changes i could see only hompage displaying with no other tabs.